# Mongoose partial text search with sorting by revelance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to query my mongodb database via mongoose, sorting the most relevant items first.

The following code works, but only returns results that contain the search parameter as a full word.
E.g. `example` will return items that include fields such as, ⁣ but`{name: "example-item", description: "this is an example description"}` but `examp` won't return that same item. I'd also like for it to search across multiple fields, as my current code does.

I'm aware you can do this partial search using regex but then you're not able to sort by textScore. Is there any way to do both? Sorting after each request is not possible as it will be paginated and handling somewhat large data.

```js
let searchValue = "examp";
let matchingItems = await Items.find(
  {
    $text: {
      $search: searchValue,
    }
  },
  {
    score: {
      $meta: "textScore"
    }
  },
  {
    sort: {
      score: {
        $meta: "textScore"
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Example DB data:

```json
[
  {name: "dignissim", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."},
  {name: "Fusce eget.", description: "Nullam malesuada ex sit amet diam ultrices"},
  {name: "Duis nec", description: "Proin at dolor at est porta aliquet. Proin viverra imperdiet orci, a ornare tortor"},
  {name: "Mauris.", description: "Aenean tristique ante et eros porttitor, ut sodales ipsum pulvinar."},
  {name: "Pellentesque", description: "Nam dignissim ipsum a elit fermentum"},
  {name: "facilisis augue", description: "Etiam sit amet dolor sed sapien rutrum sodales."},
  {name: "erat suscipit", description: "this is an example description"},
]
```

My schema is defined as below:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
});

schema.index({ name: "text", description: "text" });

const Items = mongoose.model("Item", schema);
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data from your DB?

Comment: @FiddlingAway Added some as well as my schema